# C code to generate cache-misses in page cache?

Tags: c, linux, caching, page-caching

A cache (also refer to as L1, L2 or L3 cache) is a SRAM near the CPU that help improving DRAM data access. In the other hand, [a page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) (or disk cache) is a transparent cache for the pages originating from a secondary storage device such as a hard disk drive. Additionnaly, the linux operating system build the page cache by using unused DRAM memory.

I found many code around which can produce cache miss on SRAM (ie. L1, L2 or L3), I am interested on a C code to generated cache miss at the level of the page cache (or is it better to says page-fault?).

My understanding is that such a code have to deal with file system operations such as read and write. So I design a code to read data from file with the O_DIRECT flag, the idea is that each read operation will request access to the disk a therefore cause a cache-miss in the page cache. Here is the code where /tmp/data is a 4 KB (a size of a page) file full of 0 created using `dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/data count=4K` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DATA_SIZE 10000

int main(){

  char page_data[DATA_SIZE];

  clock_t begin, end;

  double time_spent;

  int lap;

  int fd;

  fd = open("/tmp/data", "O_DIRECT", "r");

  for(lap=0; lap < 10; lap++){

    begin = clock();

    read(fd, page_data, DATA_SIZE);

    end = clock();

    time_spent = (double) (end - begin); // / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("lap %d : time spent : %f data : %s \n", lap, time_spent, page_data);

    lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);

  }

  close(fd);    

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the output of the code with additionnal information provided by the perf-tool

```
perf stat -B -e cpu-clock,task-clock,task-clock,cycles,context-swtiches,cpu-mogrations,page-faults,cache-references,cache-misses ./read_a_file

lap 0 : time spent : 1.000000 data :  
lap 1 : time spent : 1.000000 data :  
lap 2 : time spent : 1.000000 data :  
lap 3 : time spent : 0.000000 data :  
lap 4 : time spent : 0.000000 data :  
lap 5 : time spent : 0.000000 data :  
lap 6 : time spent : 1.000000 data :  
lap 7 : time spent : 0.000000 data :  
lap 8 : time spent : 0.000000 data :  
lap 9 : time spent : 1.000000 data :  

Performance counter stats for './read_a_file':

      0,282623      cpu-clock (msec)                                            
      0,282361      task-clock (msec)         #    0,024 CPUs utilized          
             0      cycles                    #    0,000 GHz                    
             3      context-switches          #    0,011 M/sec                  
             0      cpu-migrations            #    0,000 K/sec                  
            54      page-faults               #    0,191 M/sec                  
             0      cache-references          #    0,000 K/sec                  
             0      cache-misses              #    0,000 K/sec                  

   0,011596405 seconds time elapsed
```

The problem is that perf shows that no cache-misses occured during the code which I found surprising even if I can not explain why. Otherwise 54 page-faults occured, which I also find strange since my code only ask for 1 file (which size is a page size) only 10 times (not 54 time).

So my question is how to design a better code to systematically generated a cache-miss on page cache (or page-fault) ?

Any comment is welcome

Comment: Faulting to disk occurs when the physical memory is smaller than the memory needed by the program. For example, if you have a machine with 4GB of physical memory, then a program that attempts to use 5GB of memory will generate page faults. Warning: thrashing your hard drive may cause it to wear out sooner.

Comment: @user3386109, You mean the program I am looking for is the one which can causes disk swap on demand ?

Comment: I'm suggesting that the `page-faults` number comes from the virtual memory manager. Which means that you need to use a lot of memory if you want some control over the `page-faults` number.